# How to trigger/refer a custom JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, object, css-animations

I've created a javascript **animation** object inside a div with **#box** id, but my problem is I can't refer to the animation object outside the function.

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/bfojB?editors=101

Here is my code:

```
$('#box').each(function(index, element)
{
          var kkc = new TimelineLite({
            paused:true
          });

          kkc.to($("#box") , .4, {left:100,ease:Power1.easeInOut});

          element.animation = kkc; 

});

$('#box').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#box').animation.play(); //this doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are mixing up jQuery objects with DOM objects and you use one in one place and the other elsewhere and since they are not the same, your code doesn't work.

When you do:

```
element.animation = kkc;
```

You are adding a custom property named `animation` to a DOM object.

When you try to do this:

```
$('#box').animation.play();
```

You are trying to access a custom property `animation` on a jQuery object which does not exist.

---

If you want to stick with the custom DOM property, you could use this code:

```
$('#box').on('mouseenter', function(){
    this.animation.play(); 
});
```

because `this` in your event handler is the DOM object.

---

The more jQuery way of doing this (which avoids adding your own custom properties to a DOM object) would be like this:

```
$('.box').each(function(index, element)
{
          var kkc = new TimelineLite({
            paused:true
          });

          kkc.to($(this) , .4, {left:100,ease:Power1.easeInOut});

          $(element).data("animation", kcc); 

});



$('.box').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).data("animation").play();
});
```

---

Also, I might ask why you're using `$('#box').each()` as there should only be one object that matches the `#box` selector so you shouldn't need to use `.each()` to iterate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, actually I'm just simplifying my problem in this example so that you guys can understand my question easily, but didn't realise I use and id instead of class. My actual code actually consist of 10 different elements and I need to access them individually without repeating my code. That's why I need to use .each() :)

Comment: I've created another sample using the jquery way you suggested, however, I cant seem to make it work and I get this "invalid left-hand side assignment" error. http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/Hiaqg?editors=101 can you help me out with this? Thanks a lot

Comment: @VincentChua - there was a typo in my suggested code (the jQuery way) in the first `.data()` line.  I've fixed that.  I've also modified the mouseenter event handler to use `$(this)` so it will work if you have more than one item you're monitoring with the event handler and I've switched the code to `.box` as the selector to show it can work with more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the animation to the element using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). For example:

```js
var kkc = new TimelineLite({...});
// ...
$('#box').data("animation", kkc);


$('#box').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#box').data("animation").play();
});
```

NB. You used `$('#box').each(...)` in your sample, which would imply that you expect to have multiple elements with the ID `box` in the DOM. Normally IDs should be unique within the DOM, so I have removed the unnecessary use of `each` in the sample code here.

Comment: Actually my code is far more complicated, the sample code above is just something I simply draft out but didn't realize I should use class instead of id. Yes I do need to use .each(). :)

Comment: That makes sense. If you do have multiple elements that you're operating on, be aware that `.data()` will only get data for the first one. So you'll want to do something like the following to play the animations of all matched elements: `$("selector").each(function(i, el) { $(el).data("animation").play(); })`